Avoid unnecessary account generation
For context, I am trying to implement a contract I have on solidity to solana.
On solidity, I have a function like this, which writes data to state based on a condition.
function handleMessage(bytes memory data)  {
    DataMessage memory dataMessage = DataMessage.parseFrom(data);
    if dataMessage.type = DataMesssage.TYPE1 {
        data1[msg.sender] = dataMessage.data
    } else if dataMessage.type = DataMessage.TYPE2 {
        data2[msg.sender] = dataMessage.data
    }
}

On solana however, if I try to implement sth like that, I will create 2 accounts, when I do not need to create 2 accounts?
pub fn handle_message(ctx: Context<HandleMessage>, message: DataMessage) -> Result<()> {
        let sender = ctx.accounts.sender.key();
        
        match message.message_type {
            DataMessageType::TYPE1 => {
                let data_account1 = &mut ctx.accounts.data_account1;
                require!(data_account1.owner == sender, MyError::Unauthorized);
                data_account1.data = message.data;
            },
            DataMessageType::TYPE2 => {
                let data_account2 = &mut ctx.accounts.data_account2;
                require!(data_account2.owner == sender, MyError::Unauthorized);
                data_account2.data = message.data;
            },
        }

        Ok(())
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct HandleMessage<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub sender: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, ...)]
    pub data_account1: Account<'info, DataAccount1>,
    #[account(init, ...)]
    pub data_account2: Account<'info, DataAccount2>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct DataAccount1 {
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
}

#[account]
pub struct DataAccount2 {
    pub data: Vec<u8>,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
}


Is there better way to implement this function, and not create second account? Provided I cannot change the functionality of this function and split into 2 external function based on the cases.
I think I can just transfer all lamports from unused function back to the sender, but I don't think it's correct way of handling this problem.
Or, I can have separate functions to initialize Data1 or Data2, and then, update the ctx of handle_message to this, but I ideally would not want to create other methods for this.
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct HandleMessage<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub sender: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub data_account1: Account<'info, DataAccount1>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub data_account2: Account<'info, DataAccount2>,
}

**Is this acceptable way? **:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct ContextA{
  #[account(init....)]
  pub data1 Account<>;

  #[account(init....)]
  pub data2 Account<>;
  ...

  #[account(init....)]
  pub data3 Account<>;
  ...

}


pub fn function_a(ctx: Context<A>, data: Vec<u8>) -> Result<()> {
  let a = StructA::try_from(data).unwrap();

  let b = StructA::try_from(a.info).unwrap();

  // nested encoded data, complex logics, which is executed to obtain k

  let k = .. ;

  match k.message_type() {
    00 => {
      data1.value = k.something;
      
      // Since I do not need accounts data2 and data3
      // transfer all lamports of data2 and data3 accounts to signer ?
    },
    01 => {
      // similar logic as 00 ??
    },
    10 => {
      // similar logic as 00 ?
    },
    _ => {},
  }

}


I think there are multiple approaches how to manage your code. I can put some that're coming to my mind.

Having two accounts and using the Anchor init_if_needed (https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/account-constraints#normal-constraints) and having just one instruction that creates the account if it does not exist (i.e., you can omit the initialize function when you don't like it). As you write you want to create only one account then it's probably not what you expect.
As both accounts contains the same account data type (i.e., data and owner) why you don't use init for one account and fill into it data in dependence on the TYPE? Then offchain needs to verify the account data to say what type of data is within the pubkey but still seems okeyish, maybe.

Using really only one account if it's something you prefer. The Solana account has got limit for the size to 10MB (https://solana.com/docs/core/accounts) while for initialization you can define account only in size of 10KB and then increases size of account continuously (see https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html#method.realloc, and realloc at Anchor https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/account-constraints#normal-constraints)
Then you can probably to define the account data as optional and fill only when you need to place data there, kind of


#[account]
pub struct DataAccount {
    pub data1: Vec<u8>,
    pub owner1: Option<Pubkey>,
    pub data2: Vec<u8>,
    pub owner2: Option<Pubkey>,
}


I don't think there is some trouble in returning all lamports to signer within the same instruction. Just there could be maybe problem with CU limitation if you do it too extensively (https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-optimize-compute). You can use the Anchor macros but you can do the same on your own in the contract code. So you can use just UncheckedAccount and just initialize it manually within your code when you assume you need it
i.e, https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/system_instruction/fn.create_account.html#, I think an example code for dynamic creating of account could be e.g., here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210014/manually-creating-a-pda-in-the-instruction-function


Got it, thank you! It was helpful!
